# Creating files from each line of text in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file that contains lines of text like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I want to create a file for each line and each file to contain the corresponding line of text. So, 'file 1' contains 'line 1', 'file 2' contains 'line 2', and so on.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{print > ("file_" NR ".txt")}' file
```

will print each line to a file "file_"NR where NR is the line number of the input file.

here `split -l1` will also work but to control file name extensions you need to know the max number of files to be generated.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How to add extension to the created files, like .txt?

Comment: you just need to construct the file name as you want, see the update.

Comment: I get two errors when i try to use the new command to add extension to files: `unterminated string` and `syntax error`.

Comment: make sure you have the double quotes accounted for.  Also for some `awk`s parenthesis might be required.

Comment: Thank, now it works. I think i had forgotten to type the last quote mark, after the extension.